# Unable to get value for checkbox and radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating the html using JSON file. Now I need to pass data to the servlet. But the data being passed shows null. I am using jQuery post to pass the data.

My js file has

```
   $.getJSON('input.json',function(data)
 {
$.each(data,function(j,feild)
        {
            if(this.type=="checkbox")
            {   

            $('body #tabs #tabs-3 #server').append(this.display_name).append(INPUT_CHECKBOX).attr({name:this.name,type:this.type}).append(NEWLINE);
            }       
            else
                if(this.type=="radio")
                {   
                    var radio = '';    
                    var len = feild.values.length; 
                    for (var i = 0; i< len; i++)
                    {        
                        radio +='<input type="radio" name="group2">'+feild.values[i];  
                    }
                    $('body #tabs #tabs-3 #server').append(this.display_name).append(radio).attr({name:this.name,type:this.type}).append(NEWLINE);
                }
        });
```

The post method contains

```
function forwarddata()
{
alert('inside the function');
$.post('url', 
      {gender:$('input[type=radio]').val(),
       items:$('input[type=checkbox]').val()!= undefined,
       stores:$('input[type=checkbox]').val()!= undefined
      });
}
```

Myjson file has

```
{
"gender":
                   {"display_name":"gender:",
                    "name":"gender",
                    "format":"string",
                    "type":"radio",
                    "format":"string",
                    "values":["male","female"],
                    "isMandatory":"true"
                    },


"items":  
                   { "display_name":"items:",
                     "name":"items",
                     "format":"string",
                     "type":"checkbox",
                     "values":[1,2,3,4],
                     "isMandatory":"true"
                    },


"stores":                       
                   { "display_name":"stores:",
                     "name":"motion",
                     "format":"string",
                     "type":"checkbox",
                     "values":[a,b,c,d],
                     "isMandatory":"true"
                    }
```

}

When I try printing the data in the servlet it says null... Kindly explain the correct way of posting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my JSON data.Added name attribute and the below function worked just fine
Thanks:)

```
 function forwardserverdata()
{
alert('inside the function');
$.post(''url, 
      {gender:$('body #tabs #tabs-3 #server input:radio[name=gender]:checked').val(),
       items:$('body #tabs #tabs-3 #server  input:checkbox[name=items]:checked').val()!= undefined,
       stores:$('body #tabs #tabs-3 #server input:checkbox[name=stores]:checked').val()!= undefined
      });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to format your data into a proper url with parameters --

http://whatever.com/my.php?gender=male&   etc.

Depends on what type of script you have receiving the data, but that's the way I like to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[type=checkbox]').val()!= undefined` will give you true/false, I hope you are not looking for that. Try this

```
function forwarddata()
{
alert('inside the function');
$.post('url', 
      {gender:$('input[type=radio]').val(),
       items:$('input[type=checkbox]').val(),
       stores:$('input[type=checkbox]').val()
      });
}
```